# Creating a "tee" stream in c?

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a new stream in c that when written to "splits" the input and writes it to two streams, kind of like the "tee" program in Linux.

So far I have:

```c
 void maketee(FILE *a, FILE *b, int fd) {
    int ch;
    FILE *stream;

    stream = fdopen(fd, "w");
    if (!fork()) {
       /* ??? */
    }
 }
```

I've tried reading a character at a time and writing to the two streams like:

```c
 void maketee(FILE *a, FILE *b, int fd) {
    int ch;
    FILE *stream;

    stream = fdopen(fd, "w");
    if (!fork()) {
       while((ch = fgetc(stream)) != EOF) {
          fputc(ch, a);
          fputc(ch, b);
       }
    }
 }
```

However, when I create a "tee" stream that writes to stdout and a log file, then set that as a program's stdout using close() and dup2() I immediately get a segfault.

Comment: Why are you forking? Why not just read in a char and then fputc it into two different outputs?

Comment: You need to open `stream` with `r` mode since you're reading from it, not writing to it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think OP wants to continue using standard stream functions but have the output go to two FILEs.  I'm not sure you can accomplish that in the same thread, i.e. without `fork`ing.

Comment: And presumably `fd` is the other end of a pipe that the main process is writing to.